# Program to build and update a static blog (Windows)

Tags: windows, portable, static-site-generator

I'm looking for a portable program that will run under Windows 7 and will output all files needed for a static blog, in HTML, to be readable offline and uploaded by FTP to a website if required. Real-time WYSIWYG, where possible, would be great.

The single program (so not e.g. Python plus Ablog or Ruby plus Jekyll) should input the following files

- files for each blog page, written either using an internal GUI or a text editor, perhaps in Markdown, to contain the page content, date and categories
- a file to define the blog template, preferably put together using an internal GUI, so e.g. you can choose to have "last 10 posts", either shown individually or in a pulldown menu, and the same with "archives" or "top posts" or "blogroll" etc.
- image files
- other HTML pages, if any

and output a blog with every page in HTML.

(I leave aside the comments question for the moment. They could be handled using Disqus or alternatively using PHP for this only.)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it for your purpose, but LibreOffice is available as a portable version, and will save as HTML and export as XHTML. I don't know how clean the HTML is. (I know Word had / has a reputation for exporting dirty HTML.)

It will allow the use of a template.  It can use image files.  I am not sure about its ability to bring in HTML cleanly.  The portable version is available from [LibreOffice Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/libreoffice_portable).